# VS2019 installer disappears with no trace

Tags: visual-studio

VS2019 installer disappears with no trace

Have tried the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after removing the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable. it took more than week to found the solution for this issue.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/224084/installer-wont-show-up-when-i-have-node-options-va.html